# How to remove youtube-dlg - Ubuntu Mate

Tags: apt, ppa, deb, youtube-dl

I am using Ubuntu Mate.

I installed [youtube-dl-gui](https://github.com/MrS0m30n3/youtube-dl-gui) from

http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/y/youtube-dlg/

Downloaded [youtube-dlg_0.4-1~webupd8~zesty4_all.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/y/youtube-dlg/youtube-dlg_0.4-1~webupd8~zesty4_all.deb)

Then double clicked the file and thus install it.

When I needed to remove it, I opened `synaptic` and remove the `youtube-dlg` package.

Still some of the element is remaining and it is conflicting with my `youtube-dl` program which I installed using `apt-get install youtube-dl`.

What can I do?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy youtube-dl youtube-dlg` and `which youtube-dlg` to the question.

Comment: `apt-cache policy youtube-dlg` returns `N: Unable to locate package youtube-dlg`. `youtube-dlg` is not in the repository.  I downloaded and double clicked to install it. I already removed `youtube-dlg` using `synaptic`. So, `which youtube-dlg` also return nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt purge youtube-dl
$ sudo apt purge youtube-dlg
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install youtube-dl
```

The first two commands will purge the two packages as well as the interlinking dependencies.  The third command will remove the residue that is no longer being used since both packages are purged.  The last command will perform a clean install of the `youtube-dl` from the repository.

Comment: The only issue with this answer is  `sudo apt install youtube-dl` install a old version. The method workes for me is `sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` & then `sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` as mentioned in https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Comment: I notice your question changed.  I was addressing the method of retrieving it from the repository (the one you originally referred from **Synaptic**).  The main concern was to clean out the residue that was causing the conflict and to help you to have a starting clean point.  It's common for users to get the latest versions of their favorite apps from the developers or other more recent distributions other than the default repository, which is usually at least one version earlier.  Thanks for the acknowledgment of merit in the answer.  Welcome to Askubunt!

Comment: I got confused when I installed a package using double click and even after removing it from `synaptic` it was giving trouble.